# Window.open-ing to the same popup, even from multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

Here is a simple HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" value="open popup" onclick="window.open('http:\\www.example.com', 'popupName', 'width=100, height=100');">
</body>
</html>
```

so when you click on the button, a new popup will be created and no matter how many times you click it, that popup will be refreshed from now on.
Thats right. But if you opened my HTML in 2 tabulators? Then 2 popups will be opened, no matter if their names are the same. How to have actually one popup then?

Comment: I don't believe you can. The references to open windows are per-parent tab.

Comment: Without intervention of a chrome extension, this isn't possible.

Comment: "tabulators" <-- um?

Comment: @epascarello: "tab" :)